# Transposing a 3d list (Python)

Tags: python

How can I transpose the 3d list `m4c` so that I get the desired output?

```
m4c = [[['A ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['B ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['C ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  \n']],    [['E ', 'F#', 'E ', 'E ', 'F#', 'E ', '  ', 'E '], ['E ', 'F#', 'E ', 'E '], ['E ', 'F#', 'E ', 'E ', 'F#', '  ', 'E ', 'F#']]]
```

desired output:

```
[[['A ','E '], ['  ','F#'], ['  ','E '], ['  ','E '], ['  ','F#'], ['  ','E '], ['  ','  '], ['  ','E ']], 
 [['B ','E '], ['  ','F#'], ['  ','E '], ['  ','E ']],
 [['C ','E '], ['  ','F#'], ['  ','E '], ['  ','E '], ['  ','F#'], ['  ','E '], ['  ','  '], ['  ','E ']]]
```

Comment: That thread is mine, but I do not understand how to transpose in general (I have multiple input lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your `m4c[0][2]` is correct:`['C ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  \n']`, but if it and tuple is OK for you, then a simple solution can be:

```
>>> [zip(m4c[0][i], m4c[1][i]) for i in range(len(m4c[0]))]
[[('A ', 'E '), ('  ', 'F#'), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', 'F#'), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', '  '), ('  ', 'E ')],\
 [('B ', 'E '), ('  ', 'F#'), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', 'E ')], \
 [('C ', 'E '), ('  ', 'F#'), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', 'F#'), ('  ', '  '), ('  ', 'E '), ('  \n', 'F#')]]
```

Or more general:

```
>>> [zip(*[m4c[j][i] for j in range(len(m4c))]) for i in range(len(m4c[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks mostly match your desired output to me:

```
>>> pprint(m4c)
[[['A ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '],
  ['B ', '  ', '  ', '  '],
  ['C ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  \n']],
 [['E ', 'F#', 'E ', 'E ', 'F#', 'E ', '  ', 'E '],
  ['E ', 'F#', 'E ', 'E '],
  ['E ', 'F#', 'E ', 'E ', 'F#', '  ', 'E ', 'F#']]]
>>> trans = list(zip(*x) for x in zip(*m4c))
>>> pprint(trans)
[[('A ', 'E '),
  ('  ', 'F#'),
  ('  ', 'E '),
  ('  ', 'E '),
  ('  ', 'F#'),
  ('  ', 'E '),
  ('  ', '  '),
  ('  ', 'E ')],
 [('B ', 'E '), ('  ', 'F#'), ('  ', 'E '), ('  ', 'E ')],
 [('C ', 'E '),
  ('  ', 'F#'),
  ('  ', 'E '),
  ('  ', 'E '),
  ('  ', 'F#'),
  ('  ', '  '),
  ('  ', 'E '),
  ('  \n', 'F#')]]
```